# Precision of LinearProgramming with irrationals from trigonometry

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

I am solving my problem with `LinearProgramming`. In certain cases, my coefficients that are fed into the function come from evaluating trigonometric functions, $\sin(\frac{\pi}{N})$ or $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{N})$ for different $N$. Their values are problematic for the solver, for example the Interior Point Method gives the following warnings:

> Min::meprec: Internal precision limit \$MaxExtraPrecision = 500.` reached while evaluating 1/2-Sin[π/8]^2+1/2 (-1+2 Sin[π/8]^2).

The solution is produced at the end but as the effect of the machine precision arithmetic. I need to obtain exact solutions. There is the same problem with the Simplex method. I have constraints which are equalities and it is necessary to solve the problem exactly.

Are there any numerical tricks or Mathematica options that would handle these irrational numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be perilously slow, but with `Method -> Simplex` I believe one can set `WorkingPrecision -> Infinity`. Even so, this will not fully address the issue of failure to recognize zero.